# Any way to let the use of function pointers as template arguments easier?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I can use function pointer as template argument as the following

```
template<class R, class T, R (*Fun)(T)>
class MyClass;
```

Any way to make it is easy as

```
MyClass<&MyFun> a;
```

Comment: I could imagine a helper template class (/struct) that just provides a public typedef for the function pointer signature.

Comment: I'm sure I saw this asked yesterday.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Me too, the OP uses the same code. But the questions context was different, it goes to the crucial point now I guess.

Comment: I realized this is exactly the same problem (conceptually) I have posted here : [Pretty-print types ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092058/pretty-print-types-and-class-template-along-with-all-its-template-arguments)

Comment: Extend the C++ standard to allow `auto` template parameters with specialization?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a horrible answer, but I cannot think of a better one.

```
template<typename R, typename Arg, R(*Fun)(Arg)>
class MyClass {};

template<typename R, typename Arg>
struct MyClassHelper {
  template<R(*Fun)(Arg)>
  struct Class {
    typedef MyClass<R, Arg, Fun> type;
  };
};

template<typename R, typename Arg>
MyClassHelper<R, Arg> GetMyClass(R(*Fun)(Arg)); // no impl

void MyFun(int) {}

int main() {
  typedef decltype( GetMyClass(&MyFun) ) A;
  typedef A::Class<&MyFun> B;
  typedef B::type a;
  // or, in one line:
  decltype( GetMyClass(&MyFun) )::Class<&MyFun>::type b;
}
```

which is ugly as sin.  But at least it extracts the argument types of `MyFun` without repeating them...

Comment: Is that *easier* than what the OP already has which is *just* `MyClass<R, T, &MyFun> obj;`?

Comment: @Nawaz Sort of.  You don't need to know the return type and argument types of MyFun.  That's about the only advantage.  Well, and you could do `#define MYCLASS(x) decltype( GetMyClass(x) )::Class<x>::type` if you wanted to be crude...

Comment: I think if a programmer knows the function-name, he also knows (or can know) the return type and parameter types, without much effort. That is not a problem. The problem I think is too-much-typing, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible exactly as in the question, but **yes** it's possible if you flex your design a little bit. Let's take an example:
Suppose you have below function:

```
int foo (int i) { return i; }
```

Now you want to write:

```
MyClass<&foo> a; // instead of `Myclass<int, int, &foo> a;
```

Here how you will achieve it. First change the simple function:

```
int foo (int i) { return i; }
```

to encapsulated function object:

```
struct foo { // <--- function name here
  int operator () (int i) { return i; } // <--- function body here
};
```

Both are *almost* same (in the case of function object an extra `this` pointer is passed which doesn't happen in the free function case):

```
int x = foo(2); // 1st case
int x = foo_(2); // 2nd case where `foo_` is an object of `struct foo`
```

Now you can use simply as you want!

```
template<class Func>
class MyClass {...}
MyClass<foo> a;
```

Here is a [working demo](http://ideone.com/wrV7Ht).

Comment: Also note that `foo()(2)` works for the struct case.  Sadly (?), there is no `static operator()` syntax that lets you do `foo(2)` where `foo` is a `struct` (ie, replace constructor syntax with one that returns a type of your choice).

Answer (score -1):

There's already [`std::ptr_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/ptr_fun/). With C++11, you can use it as

```
auto a = std::ptr_fun(&MyFun);
```

*Update*:

As the other attempts, and non attempts BTW, have shown, isn't it possible with your kind of template, least of all "as easy as" ;-). What you can do however, is sort of reimplement the existing standard template *function* pattern (`std::ptr_fun`, `std::make_pair` and the like) to return the desired type, if your main goal is "as easy as".

Comment: @Nawaz "Any way to make it as easy as" is clear enough, at least for me.

Comment: He has a class template to which he wants to pass function-pointer as template argument in a easy way. Your answer doesn't address his problem.

Comment: Decltype with a subclass template might help, for certain values of help.