# Can a template parameter itself be templatized?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <int func(int)>
struct S : std::unary_function<int, int>
{
    int operator()(int x) const
    {
        return func(x);
    }
};

int foo(int x)
{
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    S<foo> s;

    std::cout << s(42) << std::endl;
}
```

This works okay as a way of wrapping up a function inside of a functor, which means it can be used in other templated functions (like `sort`, for example (assuming the functor had the right signature)). I don't want to create a functor struct for every possible return/argument type (and realistically I can't), and so I tried the following:

```
template <template <typename R, // Make the return type and argument type template parameters!
                    typename A> R func(A)>
struct S : std::unary_function<R, A>
{
    R operator()(A arg) const
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
};
```

That didn't work; [it gave me compilation errors](http://ideone.com/sRddD6). So then I tried:

```
template <typename R, typename A, R func(A)>
struct S : std::unary_function<R, A>
{
    R operator()(A arg) const
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
};
```

Which *did* work. Unfortunately though, I had to change instantiations of `S` to be `S<int, int, foo> s;` instead of the nicer `S<foo> s;`.

**Is it at all possible to templatize the function passed as a template argument such that I can do `S<foo> s;` and not hard code the return type and argument type of the function in `S`?**

My google-foo hasn't been able to find a specific answer.

*Edit*: Now I'm wondering if this isn't possible. I just thought of "what if `foo` is an overloaded function?" There wouldn't be, as far as I know, a way to know *which* `foo` to use when saying `S<foo> s;` and thus explicitly stating return/argument type *is* necessary. Is this correct thinking, and does this mean that the answer to my first question is "No, it's not possible"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to have a non-type template template parameter. However, the only legal syntax for template template parameters is `template < template-parameters > class`. ("A template-argument for a template template-parameter shall be the name of a class template or an alias template, expressed as id-expression." § 14.3.3)

You could create a templated class whose constructor argument was a function pointer, but I'm guessing that you're worried that will create an indirect function call.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about my worry about the indirect function call... this code is a template metaprogramming library for super computers. Thanks for the quote from the standard!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I think it's the only way to prevent necessary conversions for passing functions. 
But you can **add function templates to help you deduce the types** of (1) function args (2) function returns, like codes below:

```
template < typename R, typename A >
R result_of( R(A) );

template < typename R, typename A >
A arg0_of( R(A) );
```

Then you can use them to construct wanted function objects and let compilers do **possible optimizations**:

```
#define get_call( f ) call_t< decltype(result_of(f)), \
                              decltype(arg0_of(f)), f >()

// same as the class 'S'
template < typename R, typename A,
           R unary( A ) >
struct call_t : std::unary_function<A,R> {
    R operator()( A arg ) const {
        return unary( arg );
    }
};
```

Use the utility:

```
int neg( int arg ) {
    return -arg;
}

auto s = get_call( neg );
cout << s( 1 ) << endl;  // outputs: -1
```

It works too on function templates. Of course, you have to pass argument(s) to the template:

```
template < typename T >
T square( T arg ) {
    return arg * arg;
}

template <>
int square( int arg ) {
   cout << "square<int>()" << endl;
   return arg * arg;
}

auto sq = get_call( square<int> );
cout << sq( 12 ) << endl; // outputs: square<int>()
                          //          144
```

*Edit*: for overloaded functions, you can **do conversions** to tell compilers which version you wanna invoke:

```
int cube( int arg ) {
    return arg * arg * arg;
}

float cube( float arg ) {
    return arg * arg * arg;
}

typedef float (*chosen)( float );
auto cu = get_call( (chosen)cube );
cout << showpoint << cu( 4 ) << endl; // outputs: 64.0000
```

Comment: +1 Liked the use of decltype. However, don't call it *template function*, call it *function template*.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible. It is the same problem in principle as the following one: you wish to write just `A<100>` where `A` is defined as:

```
template<T N>
struct A {};
```

Given `N` is `100`, `T` turns out to be `int`. Fine. That is deducible by human mind, but not by the compilers even if they be 100% conformant to the C++11 Standard. I've exactly the same problem here:

- [Pretty-print types and class template along with all its template arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092058/pretty-print-types-and-class-template-along-with-all-its-template-arguments)

--

So the alternative solution I think is this:

```
template <typename R, typename A>
struct S : std::unary_function<R, A>
{
    typedef R (*Fun)(A);
    Fun func;
    S(Fun f) : func(f) {}
    R operator()(A arg) const
    {
        return func(arg);
    }
};
```

And then define `MakeS` function as:

```
template<typename R, typename A>
S<R,A> MakeS(R (*fun)(A)) 
{  
    return S<R,A>(fun); 
}
```

Which you can use it as:

```
auto s = MakeS(foo);
```

Or, simply this:

```
S<int,int> s(foo);
```

The downside with this alternative is that the function `foo` doesn't have any chance to be inlined now.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

It may not be as nice as `S<foo>` but keeps the arguments as 1 at the point of instantiation.

```
int f(int) { return 0; }


template<class R, class A> struct S
{
    typedef R(*FTYPE)(A);
    typedef R RET;
    typedef A ARG;
};

template<class R, class A> S<R, A> FW(R(f)(A));

template<class T> struct F  : std::unary_function<typename T::RET, typename T::ARG>
{

};

int main()
{
    F<decltype(FW(f))> o;
}
```

Comment: `o` doesn't bind to any function. `F` only knows about the *type* of the function, not the *function* itself.