# What is the template<typename T, T t> idiom?

Tags: c++, templates, idioms, typename, c++14

I was reading [this](http://www.meetingcpp.com/index.php/br/items/a-look-at-c14-and-beyond-papers-part-4.html) and was trying to understand what [N3601](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) was about. It said this idiom comes up a lot in a web search, but I couldn't find anything. What is the

```
template<typename T, T t>
```

idiom, what does it solve, how is it used, what is are Implicit template parameters, and what does the proposal aim to fix?

Comment: Start with a template `template <typename T> void foo(T t);`. Make that parameter a compile-time value: `template <typename T, T t> void bar();` (I think you meant that instead of `class`). Now think about how you can call `foo(5);` for T to be an `int`, but to do that with `bar`, you need `bar<int, 5>();`. Is that going in the right direction?

Comment: I did mean T t, not class T. Fixed that.

Comment: @chris I see what where you are going now. bar needs to be generic on any type we give it, but is also taking a value of that same type as another template parameter. We need to specify both the type and the value for it to deduced that 5 is an int.

The proposal shows a usage of this in a reflection library, but I've never seen it until today. How else can this be used?

Comment: +1. Ah! I loved this proposal. I think it *might* help me solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092058/pretty-print-types-and-class-template-along-with-all-its-template-arguments) which cannot be solved with C++11.

Comment: @Nawaz, Good point. I haven't actually thought about what it could allow that C++11 can't in that manner.

Comment: so cool that so many people are intersted in new C++

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem that is being solved is deducing types from template non-type parameters.

Given:

```
template<typename T> void foo(T);
template<typename T, T> void bar();
```

it is possible to deduce `T` for `foo` (for example, `foo(10)` will result in `T` being deduced to be `int`), but it is not possible to deduce `T` for `bar` (`bar<10>()` will simply not compile, you have to write it as `bar<int,10>()`).

[N3601](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) proposes fixing this by introducing the syntax:

```
template<using typename T, T> void bar();
```

which will allow `bar<10>()` to compile and cause the type `T` to be deduced.

Answer (score 5):

The paper introduction is misleading: the idiom is actually

```
 template <typename T, T t>
```

It denotes a template which depends on a type `T` and a value `t` of that type. The notation is a bit heavy since in most situations the type could be deduced from the value itself.

E.g.

```
// the current definition notation
template <typename T, T t> void f() { t.f(); };

//// the proposed definition notation
//// the parameter t depends on an implicit typename parameter T
// template <using typename T, T t> void f() { t.f(); };

struct foo {
    void f(){ 
        // some computation
    }
};

foo bar;

int main(){
    // the current instantiation notation
    f<foo,bar>(); 
    //// the proposed instantiation notation 
    //// we know that bar is of type foo, so we don't need to specify it
    // f<bar>();
}
```

The proposal is about introducing a bit of "syntactic sugar" to make the notation easier to write.

Also, the example given above is trivial in its description (and possibly wrong, since template parameters need to be `constexpr`), but the paper describes several situations where the current notation can become quite hairy, reducing readability and overall ease of programming.

Comment: and the value `t` of that type has to be an integral constant, or a pointer because nothing else is allowed in template arguments.